# Ionic V3 and the FCM Plugin

Tags: android, ionic-framework, plugins, push-notification

I was able to install FCM in my Ionic project. But as soon as I put this line on any TS file:

```
import { FCM } from '@ionic-native/fcm';
```

That page becomes inaccessible. Since the issue is happening in my Android phone, I tried to see if I could get anything from logcat, but this is all 
I get:

file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js: Line 1378 : ERROR

Anyone knows what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is solved. Here are the changes that may have solved the issue:

I opened the app.module.ts file and added this line:

import { FCM } from '@ionic-native/fcm';

Inside   providers: [] , I added FCM

I also visited the FCM plugin directory at cordova-plugin-fcm and changed the FCMPlugin.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
 }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.googleservices'
```

After all those changes, the FCM plugin for Ionic started working.